# How to deal with nihilist approaches to live a productive life?

Tags: existentialism, nihilism, positivism

Right off the bat, I'm a high school science student with no academic background in philosophy, other than mere personal interest. I've read meditations (like everyone else), general articles and have recently delved into Essays and Aphorisms by Schopenhauer out of desperation to read just anything that'll break me out of my recent,but oh so long phase.

Quite lately I find myself in a mind dump and my nonchalant attitude towards everything around me leads my inexperienced brain to credit it to a nihilistic mentality. I was wishing if i could be directed towards texts providing fresher perspectives into questions like the meaning of life, the incompetence of human and why we cease worrying about worldly stuff sometimes a little too early in life. And also yeah, how to get out of this rut. Hehehe, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to get a sense for where your head is. Nihilism is common enough in your age group (it's a stage in cognitive development that demands massive readjustments in perspective and outlook, making it vulnerable to meaning-quandaries), but that isn't really a helpful insight. Schopenhauer is probably not the best direction to go; Emerson or Thoreau might be a bit healthier for your head. Focus, clarity, and inspiration are more likely to carry you through this than (my phrase) neurotic naturalism.

Comment: I'm curious why the question title mentions productivity, and how that relates to nihilism?

Comment: @TheLoneRanger oh its cause i mentioned about my newfound nonchalant attitude towards everything and that's exactly what you don't want when one is preparing for their "highly important school graduating exams". Also i feel it's a personal minima too, since I have greatly started to look condescendingly on a lot of stuff, and thats bound to be bad if its so frequent.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley do you have any specific works of those two in your mind that I could start with?

Comment: Thoreau's 'Walden' is well worth the read, giving a view of an ascetic, philosophical life that doesn't slip into nihilism. For Emerson, any collection of his essays should work. They were originally published in two volumes,  but there are any number of 'selected works' type books out there.

Comment: I know where you've been and have tried reading myself out of that ditch. I would check out Viktor Frankl's "Man's Search for Meaning". It's very approachable and non-theoretical, which I think is paramount to getting out of nihilism and into the world again. I would also recommend going swimming.

Comment: @connor449 feels so great to know someone's been there, although obviously there must be, but still. Even I started Man's search for meaning, and I found it great! But due to school exam stuffs, it's a little on hold. It's irritating trying to find yourself amongst so much noise, and no manual provided to you. But I guess that's the struggle! Thanks for the reply.